# transformation formula in English

Tags: vector-analysis, transformation

I've tried several notations like "integral transform" and "coordinate transformation", but I don't happen to find the following theorem, easily known as "Transformationssatz" in German:
$\int_{g(u)}f = \int_{u}f \circ g \,\vert\det g'\vert$.

I enquire you as to tell me the inscribed name of this formula.

Kind regards

Comment: Change of variables formula? https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/changeofvariables.aspx

Comment: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables)

Comment: As Raymond says: "More precisely, the change of variables formula is stated in the next theorem: ...". Leon, you should write an English version for [this wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformationssatz).

Comment: @ Leon Maybe simply a transformation or conversion rule.